# How to include a local library to an executable with dune ocaml

Tags: package, ocaml, ocaml-dune

I have a project structured like this :

```
root/
|—— dune-project
|—— lib/
|  |—— dune
|  |—— Readertsp.ml
|  |-- ...
|
|—— bin/
|  |—— dune
|  |—— bin.ml
```

`bin.ml` :

```ml
let city_config = "ch130" in
let path = Readertsp.open_path city_config in ();;
```

`dune`:

```
(executable
 (name MCTS_main)
 (libraries graphics mcts)
)
```

`Readertsp.ml` : https://pastebin.com/U0h69uRy

`dune` :

```
(library
 (name mcts)
 (modules Readertsp)
 (libraries graphics))
```

When I try dune build, I get this error :

```js
File "tests/MCTS_main.ml", line 3, characters 0-19:
3 | Readertsp.open_path city_config;;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound module Readertsp
```

Do you know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a hint on the OCaml IRC/Discord.

My problem was that to access to the open_path function, I had to use

```ml
Mcts.Readertsp.Readertsp.open_path
```

Because if I don't add `(wrapped false)` to the dune mcts file, it puts all libraries in an only module called `Mcts`. With a dune file like this :

```ml
(library
 (wrapped false)
 (name mcts)
 (modules Readertsp)
 (libraries graphics))
```

I can call my function like this :

```ml
Readertsp.Readertsp.open_path
```

As highlighted by glennsl in the comment, my last mistake is that I was creating a module inside my `Readertsp.ml` file, which is already a module itself.

After deleting the `module Readertsp = struct` in my `Readertsp.ml` file, I can finally call

```ml
Readertsp.open_path
```

Comment: You don;t need to define a module named `Readertsp` inside `Readertsp.ml`. The file itself is a module.

Answer (score 0):

`dune` will auto-generate a namespace module to prevent collisions between modules with the same name from different libraries. The name of the module will be the library name capitalized. `Readertsp` should therefore be accessible as `Mcts.Readertsp`.

Note that you can also override the auto-generated namespace module by providing a similarly named module (`Mcts.ml` in this case).

Comment: Hey, with `wrapped = false` I could avoid using `Mcts.` (idk if it's a good practice or not) but not `Readertsp.Readertsp.`, do you know how to deal with that ?

Comment: Answered the latter in a comment on your answer. `wrapped = false` is not a good idea I think, as that will increase the likelihood of modules from different libraries conflicting with each other.

Comment: do I need to use Mcts.Readertsp if I want to use `Readertsp` in another module of the mcts library ?

Comment: No, the namespace module is only needed for consumers of the library.